Wine + mp3tag: CJK characters are showing up as squares
Might be best explained with an example:

So this is the folder selection dialog (this album list is from a Korean singer)

This next screenshot is the track listing after selecting an album/folder from a Japanese band.


As a test...

I tried using LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 or ja_JP.SHIFT_JIS and more than half of the characters are still showing up as squares. Since I also have Chinese/Korean albums, I think this is not the ideal solution since I do not want to switch locales/languages.
I ran "winetricks allfonts" which seems to install all Windows fonts. No change to earlier results.
I ran winecfg => Desktop Integration => Appearance and I changed the fonts (if option is available) of all items to "Noto Sans CJK JP".
I checked mp3tag and it does not have font settings like other apps (example: foobar2000).
As a another test, I installed foobar2000 and it automatically selected "Noto Sans CJK JP" as the default font. (the track/album listing shows the correct characters. It's only the folder selection dialog that is wrong. I'm guessing that feature uses built-in "Windows" dialog.

Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks
EDIT:
The first screenshot (Korean album) should be "사랑하는 사람들을 위한 지침서"
For the second screenshot (Japanese track), it should be "05. 心の地図.flac"

Can you post a few titles right here? I wanna check it on my system.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov  I edited the original post with answer to your query. Thanks a lot.

Works for me: https://imgur.com/a/xsvCCYo Wine 9.10, Fedora 40, some custom fonts.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov can you please share your "setup"? did you do anything special? how did you run mp3tag? Any other info? Thank you.

Download this file: https://mega.nz/file/flkGRRxK#WSplCEKp4EB8Ht8wCJOs6Z2G_t67l2woWPWEF2XZyGg , run tar xf Asia.tar.gz; sudo mv -iv Asia /usr/share/fonts; sudo fc-cache -frsv; log off/log on.

PERFECT! thanks so much. maybe you can make your reply as answer and I'll mark it as such. In any case, thanks a lot!
